# iSCSI: ubuntu tgt with Windows Initiator

Tags: iscsi

A Question from my iSCSI-Lab: I'm trying to configure Windows systems (10 + Server 2019) to connect to an Ubuntu iSCSI target, using tgt on Ubuntu and the Windows built-in initiator. Windows initiators connect happily to Windows, FreeNAS and AsusTor targets. Ubuntu initiators connect happily to the Ubuntu target. My only issue is with Windows initiators and Ubuntu / tgt as the target.

On Windows "Quick Connect" finds the target, but the GUI says "The target name is not found or is marked as hidden from login." and Event log says "iSCSIPrt / ID 10 / Login request failed".

On Ubuntu tgt doesn't seem to log much, only service starts and such.

I've tried no authentication, IQN, IP and (mutual) CHAP for authentication, no luck...

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Ubuntu does not conform to RFC 3722 "String Profile for iSCSI Names" which states "In addition, any upper-case characters input via a user interface MUST be mapped to their lower-case equivalents."

My host is named UV1, so I set up an IQN like "iqn....:UV1-test" but the Windows initiator connects to "iqn....:uvi1-test" which is met with a "Target not found" ...